# Select the first <img> tag after an <input> tag using xpath

Tags: html, xpath

I have HTML as given below :

```
<root>
 <Customer cid= "C1" name="Janine" city="Issaquah">
  <input name="Client.ClaimsAdjudicationPendReason" />
  <a onclick="javascript:pendReasonLookup('MFM_Pend Reason', 'PendReason','txtClaimsAdjudicationPendReason','','')>
            <img title="Lookup" class="imgSearchIcon" alt="Lookup" src="/F005web/images/search.gif"/>


<input name="Client.ClaimsAdjudication" />
    <a onclick="javascript:pendReasonLookup('MFM_Pend Reason', 'PendReason','txtClaimsAdjudication','','')>
            <img title="Lookup" class="imgSearchIcon" alt="Lookup" src="/F005web/images/search.gif"/>

  </Customer>  
</root>
```

Using the below xpath, I'm able to selected the 'input' node where

```
name="Client.ClaimsAdjudicationPendReason"

xpath:=//input[@name='Client.ClaimsAdjudicationPendReason']
```

But I need to select the `img` node (just below `a` tag) where

```
name="Client.ClaimsAdjudicationPendReason"
```

Comment: The html is invalid the <a> tags aren't closed and their onclick attributes don't have close quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The original html had some bits missing, see my comment above. So assuming this is what was intended:

```
<root>
    <Customer cid="C1" name="Janine" city="Issaquah">
        <input name="Client.ClaimsAdjudicationPendReason" />
        <a onclick="javascript:pendReasonLookup('MFM_Pend Reason', 'PendReason','txtClaimsAdjudicationPendReason','','')" />
        <img title="Lookup" class="imgSearchIcon" alt="Lookup" src="/F005web/images/search.gif" />
        <input name="Client.ClaimsAdjudication" />
        <a onclick="javascript:pendReasonLookup('MFM_Pend Reason', 'PendReason','txtClaimsAdjudication','','')" />
        <img title="Lookup" class="imgSearchIcon" alt="Lookup" src="/F005web/images/search.gif" />
    </Customer>
</root>
```

The xpath below will select the first `img` node after `input` with `name`  "Client.ClaimsAdjudicationPendReason"

```
//input[@name="Client.ClaimsAdjudicationPendReason"]/following-sibling::img[1]
```